# How to limit number of outputs from external URL

Tags: reactjs, count, react-hooks

I am fetching the data from url in my list search. Right now when I click on input, the list with all data from url shows up, but I need to limit it - show only 5 items and the rest has to be scrolled.

The way I am fetching data

```
const dataInfo = "secretURL"

const [myData, setMyData] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        getDataInfo();
    }, []);

    const getDataInfo = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await fetch(dataInfo);
        const jsonData = await response.json();
        const { array1, array2 } = jsonData;
        const combinedData = array1.map(({ data1 }, i) => ({
          ...data1,
          ...array2[i].data2 
        }));
        setMyData(combinedData); 
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err)
      }
   };
```

How can I include into this code a function, which will count the number of items ? Or what is an appropriate way to handle this ?

Fetching data:

```
{ myData && myData.map(( data1, data2, index)  =>
        <li key={"index" + index}  >
                    <h5>{data1.name} </h5>
                    <p>{data2.color} </p>
        </li>
         )}
```

Expected output:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 'cleanest' way to do this would be to calculate the height of the first five items and then put this height as a max-height on the container of these items. You can then add an overflow: scroll to the container css.
It's a lot of work though and I could not imagine you would want 'exactly' five items?

I would suggest a max-height on the container, more or less 'estimated'.

e.g.: if every item has a height of 100px you could add a max-height: 500px on the container with an overflow: scroll;

The solution is thus more a css solution then a react solution

Comment: I am sorry for confusing post, but yes - you did get it right. I need to fetch all items, but show only 5 when input is clicked and the rest can be scrolled. I tried to implement your solution, unfortunately it does not do anything. Also using setSliceByNumber is not necessary anywhere ? Perhaps include it to useEffect or something

Comment: My answer is updated, there was a little fault. Although I don't think my answer is an answer on your question. I'm still not really sure what your goal is. What do you mean with 'the rest can be scrolled'. Do you have an example online?

Comment: I updated my post with expected output - hope it clears up my idea. The solution you updated didn't work either.

Comment: My answer has nothing to do with what you want, I'll write a new one :)

Comment: I thought the solution could be done with React, although css solution works just fine. Thanks.